# Apache: 3 virtual hosts working perfectly, 1 is not, but settings seem to be the same (Mac)

Tags: apache, virtualhost

(OSX Leopard 10.5.8)

I've been using virtual hosts with no problems until now, when I tried to make a new block of code for the next one. The offender is called **project1**.

I've got an `index.php` sitting in the `project1/html/` folder, just like all the others. But every time I try to go to `http://project1/` in the browser I get a 404.

Here's the contents of **httpd-vhosts.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Users/sebu/_SERVER/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName skeleton
    DocumentRoot "/Users/sebu/_SERVER/skeleton/public_html/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pickle
    DocumentRoot "/Users/sebu/_SERVER/pickle/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project1
    DocumentRoot "/Users/sebu/_SERVER/project1/html/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's what I've checked already:

- I restarted Apache (every time I change something).
- I tried clearing the browser cache.
- I tried rebooting.
- I made sure the file permissions are exactly the same as the other working vhosts (dirs and files).
- I've got the line `Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` in **httpd.conf** (turning `Multiviews` off was the solution to an earlier problem).
- I ran `httpd -S` to check the syntax and it said everything was OK.
- I tried pinging `project1` just to check and sure enough it says `cannot resolve project1: Unknown host`

(Not sure if it's worth mentioning, but when I did a `ls -la` in `_SERVER/` I noticed that `project1/` had permissions written as `drwxr-xr-x@` with the `@` on the end. I read that this meant it was a quarantined file and would wait for me to open it so I ran `open project1/` and it went away.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have an entry in /etc/hosts for skeleton, pickle, but not project1? If so, add an entry for project1 and that should resolve your issue.

Comment: That was it! I knew I was forgetting something. Still learning the ropes and I set the old ones up a while ago so I'd forgotten about that. Thanks very much!

I'd vote you up but this is my first post and I don't have enough rep yet, sorry :'(

Comment: No apology necessary, glad that fixed your issue.